# How to use variables from library modules?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have problems using variables from library modules in IntellliJ IDEA 11.

My steps were:

1. Created a new Android project
2. Added new module (File->New Module) and made sure I add it as a library
3. Module was correctly recognized as a library module and became part of the main project's tree
4. I created a new class in library project and added a test variable
5. I tried to reference this variable from the main project, but it does not see it.

I've posted images showing project tree structure, library class with a public variable and error in the main project. IntelliJ did not recognize my library class and did not offer any import. Manual import of library project did not work either.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to [add the library module as a dependency](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) to the main module.

Comment: Hm, I did but it remains the same. How am I supposed to access a class in the library? Obviously I cannot access it via import or via className.SomePublicField.

Comment: I found it. Instructions on that link say that I am supposed to add "jars or directory", which is not correct. In intellij idea 11, I used the 3rd option "Module dependency" and now all works like a charm.

Comment: Instructions on that page cover all the cases, including **Adding dependencies on modules**.